# Generic Azure HTTP Function

Tags: c#, generics, get, azure-functions

Hi I have had a service running in a local blazor webassembly application which uses generic methods to get data from Azure Table using the Azure.Data.Table sdk (note similar generic methods for delete/update/create etc):

```
public async Task<List<TEntity>> GetItemsByPartitionKeyAsync<TEntity>(string tableName, string partitionKey) where TEntity : class, ITableEntity, new()
{
    try
    {
        var tableClient = new TableClient(
        new Uri(storageUri),
        tableName,
        new TableSharedKeyCredential(accountName, storageAccountKey));

        var response = tableClient.QueryAsync<TEntity>(filter: $"PartitionKey eq '{partitionKey}'");

        return await response.ToListAsync();

    }
    catch (RequestFailedException ex)
    {
        throw new Exception($"{ex.Status} - {ex.ErrorCode}");
    }
}
```

This is called with the following:

```
var rtn = await QueryAzureTableByPKAsync<*SpecificTableEntityType*>(tableName, uri, accountName,storageAccountKey,patitionKey);
```

I am now looking to add greater security to the app before I start to distribute it and am dropping the service behind an Azure Http Function.

I have about 40 POCOs that inherit from ITableEntity which get in and out of Azure Table using these single methods for create/delete/query/update - hence a desire to have a single 'generic' method each for get/post/put/delete to match the simplicity of this.

Is there a way to get say a string of the entity type name from a querystring value and use reflection or something to fill in the magical mysterious `<TEntity>` bit of the `QueryAzureTableByPKAsync<TEntity>()` method?

The client app will obviously be aware of the type used in the request and can deserialize the http response content to the correct list type etc.

it seemed so easy when I started playing with this!!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK,
You can pass the entity type in the Azure Function Http Trigger URL a Query String parameter.
Then, we have Reflection concept to create that instance type dynamically on the run time - an [article](https://www.abygeorgea.com/blog/2021/07/31/creating-classes-on-run-time-using-reflection-in-c-number/) provided by @*AbyGeorgeA* with practical code examples.

```cs
var TEntity = j.GetType() //where j is an object that stores some data.
```

This instance type is created using `Activator.CreateInstance()` Method as this is runtime assembly and format of passing parameters provided in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=net-6.0).

Later, the method `GetItemsByPartitionKeyAsync` you have defined could be interacted with the EntityType as a generic type and result can be passed to the Http Response JSON Format and also the passing of entity should be valid type format.